# Tiles not showing up properly in WP8.1 Silverlight app

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, live-tile, appxmanifest

I recently converted my Windows Phone 8.0 app to Windows Phone 8.1 Silverlight (not universal). Afterwards I changed the Notification Service to WNS because I want to use its benefits. With changing this I have to specify my tile logos in the new Package.appxmanifest file.

```
<m3:VisualElements DisplayName="Time Stamp Pro" 
    Square150x150Logo="Assets\Tiles\Logo.png"
    Square44x44Logo="Assets\Tiles\SmallLogo.png" 
    Description="Work time tracker" 
    ForegroundText="light" 
    BackgroundColor="transparent">
<m3:DefaultTile Square71x71Logo="Assets\Tiles\Square71x71Logo.png" 
    Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Tiles\WideLogo.png">
</m3:DefaultTile>
<m3:SplashScreen Image="Assets\Splashscreen\SplashScreenImage.jpg" />
</m3:VisualElements>
```

My file structure looks as follows.

[image: Assets file structure]

But when I now start the app those logos/tiles are not showing up. In other words they cannot be loaded.

[image: Tile shown after deployed]

All of the logos are white with a transparent background. They look like this (screenshot taken from paint.net so the squares in the background are just from this drawing tool)

[image]

I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong here. All the documentation didn't help me so far.

Comment: are you sure the image names are right and action set to resource?

Comment: Just double checked. Setting the action to resource didn't work either. I'm sure the names are correct. According to the documentation and Build2014 videos the framework will check for .scale-xxx as part of the name to show the correct image, depending on the device screen (so that it always looks perfect). But please correct me if I'm wrong with this convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting in contact with the appropriate people at Microsoft I know why it isn't working. Scaled resources (images with scale-xxx as part of the file name) are not supported in WP8.1 Silverlight. They require a new resources concept which is only available in Windows Universal apps. So I have to stick to the old images that I used in WP8.0 and reference them without scale-xxx.

Comment: Could you share the code how it looks when you do that?

Answer (score 0):

try to add Square310x310Logo in DefaulTile like this

```
<m3:DefaultTile  
Square71x71Logo="Assets\SquareTile71x71.png" 
Wide310x150Logo="Assets\Tiles\SquareTile310x150.png"
Square310x310Logo="Assets\Tiles\SquareTile310x310.png">
</m3:DefaultTile>
```

Comment: This doesn't help either. Square310x310Logo is ignored for WP anyway. Note that the app is WP 8.1 for Silverlight! (not universal)